# Neo4j/Cypher: How to exclude/include nodes with multiple properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a collection of nodes with multiple properties, for example:

- (:Item {id: 1, type: 10})
- (:Item {id: 2, type: 10})
- (:Item {id: 1, type: 11})
- (:Item {id: 1, type: 13})
- (:Item {id: 2, type: 11})

In other examples, I can include nodes using a single value, using a query like this (with the IN clause):

```
MATCH (x:Item) 
WHERE x.type IN [10,13] 
RETURN x
```

Im trying to include/exclude nodes with certain properties, something like the next query:

```
MATCH (x:Item) 
WHERE x IN [({id: 1, type: 10}), ({id: 2, type: 11})] 
RETURN x
```

with the above query i don't get an error, but i don't get any results either. Could it be possible so that it includes or excludes certain nodes? In the above example could be more easy do 2-MATCHs for the 2 nodes, but in the real problem i want to include/exclude more than 10 nodes dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` in your example is much more that just a map with `type` and `id`, it is an identifier that represents the complete node.

If you rewrite `x` as a map of `x.id` and `x.type` then you can make that comparison.

```
MATCH (x:Item) 
WHERE {id: x.id, type: x.type} IN [({id: 1, type: 10}), ({id: 2, type: 11})] 
RETURN x
```